# Windows dual boot access to other hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, windows, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a custom built PC with several internal HDDs running Win8. I would like to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on a second partition on the C:. Am I right in assuming I should be able to leave the other hard drives as they are currently, and just mount them in Ubuntu, which will allow both OSs to read/write them (with ostensibly no changes in the Windows side, just the files that already exist to be used by both)? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

"Probably," assuming you're using NTFS on all of your other hard drives, Ubuntu will be able to access them and read/write to them just like any other disk.